# My MongoDB Atlas database is not communicating with any IP except Localhost

Tags: javascript, mongodb, crud

I have been stuck in the last few days for MongoDB CRUD operation. My production level deployment cannot communicate with MongoDB atlas but at the same time, my localhost is able to do CRUD operation. My network access is available for any IP like 0.0.0.0/0.

All of my applications fall into the same problem. I am reset and restore my mongoDB but the problem still remains. what could I do?

Please guide what should I do.

I am reset and restore my mongoDB but the problem still remains.

Comment: How do you connect to the database?

Comment: It is a bit difficult when you don't use correct terms. What do you mean by "cannot communicate"? What is the error message? What do you mean by "my localhost is able to do CRUD operation"? localhost is an alias for an IP-Address. What do you mean by "I reset and restore my mongoDB"?

Comment: Thank you, friend. Localhost means my current IP. in development mode, my localhost is able to Get and Post requests. but at the production level after deployment. website is not able to Get and Post requests.  The problem does not only occur in one project. but also my all of other project.